# How to get next month on same day in php

Tags: php

How to get the next month on same day in php.

By using this code. I am able to get next month

```
$delidate = '2014-01-13'; // Today is Monday
$monthlyDate = strtotime("+1 month".$delidate);
$monthly = date("Y-m-d", $monthlyDate);
echo $monthly;
```

Output of this code is:- `2014-02-13`

Now, I want to get the next month date on Monday only.

I need next month **monday** day `2014-02-10`

or Suppose if day is Wednesday then i need Wednesday date on next month.

**Updated:-** Suppose if Particular day is not available on next date in that case i need nearest day in next month.

**Update:-**

I try this code

```
$delidate = '2014-01-29';
$monthlyDate = strtotime( $delidate . " +1 month " );
$monday = strtotime( date("Y-m-d", $monthlyDate) . " Monday this week " );
$monthly = date("Y-m-d", $monday);
echo $monthly;
```

It give me output **2014-03-03**
while i need 2014-02-26

Comment: What is your criteria to get the date on same day?If Today is monday then you want the next month's date of first monday?

Comment: no, I want the next date on same day. or the nearest day

Comment: So you want the nearest monday after 30 days?

Comment: right :) or suppose if today is Wednesday then i need Wednesday date after 30 days. or nearest Wednesday after 1 month

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21085118/829533

Comment: your updated code gave `2014-02-24` as output

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, since you want get same date after 1 Month

```
$delidate = '2014-01-13'; // Today is Monday
$monthlyDate = strtotime("+4 week".$delidate);
$monthly = date("Y-m-d", $monthlyDate);
echo $monthly;
```

Comment: hi Chen thanks for the answers and suppose if there is 5 week in a month then how we got the next month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$delidate = '2014-01-13';
$monthlyDate = strtotime( $delidate . " +1 month " );
$monday = strtotime( date("Y-m-d", $monthlyDate) . " Monday this week " );
$monthly = date("Y-m-d", $monday);
echo $monthly;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will take into consideration the current day not only Monday.

```
$delidate = '2014-01-13';
$monthlyDate = strtotime( $delidate . " +1 month " );
$dayname = strtotime( date("Y-m-d", $monthlyDate) . " " . date('l', strtotime($delidate)) . " this week " );
$monthly = date("Y-m-d", $dayname);
echo $monthly;
```